# Not able to open a file using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to open a file using this code but it is again and again showing the error: NameError: name "practice" is not defined
where "practice" is the name of the file which I'm trying to open.
"practice.txt" (the file that im trying to open) is present in the same directory in which my python program has been created.

```
import os
name = input("Enter the name of the file : ") 
if(os.path.exist(name)==True):
    fopen = open(name,'w')
    line = fopen.readline()
    while(line != ""):
        print(line)
        line=fopen.readline()
    fopen.close()
else:
    print("file does not exist!!!")
```

Comment: Is that Python 2?

Comment: Based on your error message, you should be using `raw_input`

Comment: python 2: `input` should be `raw_input`

Comment: You are using Python 2. Use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you must specify the PATH of the file as well as the filename.

I.E. open("Files/images/Image1.png", "MODE")

Comment: If the file is in the same directory, the path is not needed

Comment: True, @Wondercricket, but you need the file extension as well. Maybe that's what he forgot.

Comment: I didn't forget the extension. I am writing the file name alongwith the extension ".txt"  @EgMusic

Comment: @AnantVikramSingh oh, okay.